# How can I extract text in a certain position from this string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How can I extract whatever text is in the `username` position of the following string in Ruby 1.9.2?

```
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101502204713520282
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on one or more instances of / and take the 3rd part?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > string = "https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101502204713520282"
 => "https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101502204713520282" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > string.split(/\/+/)[2]
 => "username"
```

Comment: Just as a comment though, it looks like you're trying to do your own url parsing, and it's generally better to do that in routes.rb using the traditional methods rather than hack your own.